# How to select excel cells at once from a list of cell numbers

Tags: excel

How can I select cell in Microsoft Excel if I have the list of cell numbers. For example, if I have a list of cell numbers, [A1, B22, C43, D12, E9,......], and I want to select only these cells at once, how can I do so?

I tried to search online for answers, but no hint was there for this.

Comment: Using VBA …..….?

Comment: @Skin Actually I was searching if a Non-VBA answer is possible. Unfortunately, I have not used VBA before. But if no such solution is there, I will try VBA.

Comment: Ok but you want to automate that selection?!? If not, just hold down Ctrl when you select and it will select multiple cells. Otherwise, VBA for a non-cloud solution.

Comment: Create a Named Range, e.g. *MyRange*, which refers to your range union, e.g. `=$A$1,$B$22,$C$43,$D$12,$E$9`. You can then use the **GoTo** command, typing MyRange in the *Reference* box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From <kbd>**HOME**</kbd> tab select <kbd>Find & Select</kbd> then <kbd>Go To</kbd>.
- Input your preferred ranges in `References` separating by comma to select discontinuous ranges.

[image]

Comment: Another option is to type your desired range `A1, B22, C43, D12, E9` to `Name Box` (top left corner) beside formula bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `=A1, B22, C43, D12, E9` to select the cells

[image: example]

Comment: That doesn't actually "select" the cells. It creates a `formula` which refers to that range of cells. Using this method you would not, for example, be able to apply formatting to that range of cells.